# How to remove top border of gradient text in safari

Tags: html, css

I added the text gradient using CSS but how can I remove the top border of the gradient.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="main-menu-links main-menu">
   <li><a (click)="navigateToHome()">+ HOME</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`i have put in <a> tag`

```
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4900 0%, #ec00c4 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 30px;`
```

[image]

**when I remove**

```
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4900 0%, #ec00c4 100%);
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

**then it will remove gradient as well border to**

Comment: on what element did you apply the gradient ?

Comment: I have put it in <a> tag

Comment: I don't see any gradient over your `+ Home` anchor. It's not there... nothing to do... problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your  tag in the style sheet

```
a { border-top: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you should be getting a top border for the `a` unless there is `border-top` specified somewhere in the styles.
If so, just make it none or 0.

```
border-top: none;
```

or

```
border-top: 0;
```