# How to remove strange border from text gradient on safari?

Tags: css, text, safari, gradient

text gradient on safari makes some bug which doesn't exist on Firefox or Chrome. I use Safari 13.0.5. See screenshot

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WZF9.png)

I am trying to put a gradient on some text with that code:

```css
.vs-plus-text {
  max-height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}

.p1 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ab1d5b, #d92c48);
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="vs-plus-text hover-plus-vs12 hover-plus-res">
  <p class="p1">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Tried to add some margin, padding, line-height etc, but when I remove this "top border or left border
" I get border on other side. Border property doesn't affect on it.

I found similar or almost exact problem but there is no solution.

[Link to similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851151/how-to-remove-top-border-of-gradient-text-in-safari)

Thanks for help.

Comment: I made your code a live snippet, can you confirm or infirm that it does reproduce said behavior on your config? On my Safari 13.1 on a retina display, I can't reproduce.

Comment: I don't see the problem in my safari Version 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8).

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem by using svg to render my gradient text.

#### React Demo

```
<div className="countdown">
  <svg
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
    }}>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" x2="0%" y1="0" y2="100%">
        <stop stopColor="#ffe19b" offset="0%" />
        <stop stopColor="#f3cb6f" offset="100%" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <text
      fill="url(#gradient)"
      dominantBaseline="middle"
      textAnchor="middle">
      <tspan x="50%" y="50%">
        {seconds}
      </tspan>
    </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Code Pen Demo](https://codepen.io/brenna/pen/mybQVx?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=70742ffe9e22cb5fc2e592663a8c6ab0ff6e4b9b-1597209898-0-AUvWd9TpsJZeYjIUhmOCC7TogUj1g4JsBFwCI6CNxpA1K5xeumcAjHGlII-Ji1x5186JYVhsBhPlwexRieIRb4Q5LAamAqKlYllDgGY6yUnFwEqkUtVidtHdi8et-YqcYrOSNWqi-6wPl3a-Jt5m6ttEdMhBCug6c0X9oxpkcDY52fiTmXzErYHjN8u-zi3YBUkTWquUeAooPVUozVnrgi6N5q3PZgB3AauIVvsc6d62W7tmy4rSRuDFMfYys2LSbEUeIMph1Hz19nyRQGneOmePokiLp6EvFSVW25qYSgiyevnELicduw2Q22x-hrYt_ymyF5HbITocyCBQJrowSogB34kcq3JTgx-wk0uP_J3g)